# why my nav controller is nil even after embedding navigation controller in story board and using push segue?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have tried to read several threads on Stackoverflow, but I think that I have implemented all of them but still it doesn't work. here is my storyboard

[image]

so I hide (uncheck) the navigation bar visibility like the image below, because I want to implement my own 'navigation header' like in the image above (in the right) :
[image]

and when the back button is pressed, I use the code below:

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

but unfortunately, after I check, the navigation controller is nil and I can't get back to previous VC.

I set some code in the app delegate like this, in order to set the navigation. if the user has already login then it will be navigated to HomeVC (main tab bar), otherwise it will be directed to login sequence like my storyboard above

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        // to print Local Database Location, uncomment the line below if you want to trace the location of Realm Database / User Default
        // print("Location of Realm Database: \(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL)")



        checkHasLoggedInOrNot()




        return true
    }




}

extension AppDelegate {
    // MARK: - Helper Methods

    func checkHasLoggedInOrNot() {
        let userHasLoggedIn = AuthService.shared.hasLoggedIn

        if userHasLoggedIn {
            goToMainTabBar()
        } else {
            goToAuthVC()
        }
    }


}

extension AppDelegate {
    // MARK: - Navigation

    func goToMainTabBar() {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: StoryBoardName.Main.rawValue, bundle: nil)
        let mainTabBar = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: MainStoryboardData.StoryBoardID.MainTabBar.rawValue)
        window?.rootViewController = mainTabBar
    }

    func goToAuthVC() {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: StoryBoardName.Auth.rawValue, bundle: nil)
        let authVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: AuthStoryboardData.StoryBoardID.AuthVC.rawValue)
        window?.rootViewController = authVC
    }
}
```

maybe the problem is the code below ?

```
func goToAuthVC() {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: StoryBoardName.Auth.rawValue, bundle: nil)
        let authVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: AuthStoryboardData.StoryBoardID.AuthVC.rawValue)
        window?.rootViewController = authVC
    }
```

because it is pointed to AuthVC ? not to Navigation Controller ?

what went wrong in here ?

Comment: From where you are calling - `self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)` ?

Comment: @AmirKhan from the VC that has back button ( the right one on the first image)

Comment: Are you setting your firstController as rootViewController and secondly how you are pushing your second Controller, show some code ?

Comment: and you `segue` to push to next viewController? Check `navigation stack` whether it's empty or not.

Comment: I add some codes, I initiate the VC from the appdelagate. @MuhammadWaqasBhati I don't know how to see the firstVC as the rootVC or not

Comment: @AmirKhan yes I push to next VC. I add some code above, maybe the problem is when I initialize the VC from my app delegate

Comment: You are not assign Navigation controller as root controller in goToAuthVC() method. So In your stack there is no navigation cotroller. So please init with navigation controller instead of authVC.

Comment: Is `AuthVC` the yellow view controller in your screen shot?  If so, that is your problem.  You are creating the yellow VC, not the navigation controller.  You need to create the navigation controller. If you want to use storyboards, then rather than this approach I would create a view controller to be your initial view controller and have it perform the appropriate segue based on the user's authentication status

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Push/Pop` only be possible if there is `Navigation stack` in `window`.

Replace your `goToAuthVC` with following -

```
func goToAuthVC() {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: StoryBoardName.Auth.rawValue, bundle: nil)
    let authVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: AuthStoryboardData.StoryBoardID.AuthVC.rawValue)
    let navigationController  = UINavigationController(rootViewController: authVC)
    window?.rootViewController = navigationController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

}
```